# How to know which row has the greatest sum

Tags: c, arrays

I am writing this program to find the sum of each row, and find the row with the highest sum. however, the sums of each row execute perfectly, but I can't be shown the highest sum.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int type[5][3]={{3,31,19},{34,2,1},{0,0,9},{3,0,6},{11,9,5}};
    for(i=0;i<5;++i) 
    {
        for(j=0;j<3;++j) 
        {
            sum=sum+type[i][j];
            if((sum=sum+type[i][j])>(sum=sum+type[i+1][j]))
            {
                printf("%d type is highest",i);
            }
        }
        printf("Total sumt %d=%d\n",i+1,sum);
        sum=0;
    }
}
```

Comment: `int biggest = INT_MIN;` (in `stdlib.h`) then after computing the sum and exiting your inner loop, `if (sum > biggest) biggest = sum;` and then output `biggest` after your outer loop completes. You should declare and initialize `int sum = 0;` immediately after `for(i=0;i<5;++i) {` You don't need to reset at the end that way.

Comment: Undefined behavior: `if((sum=sum+type[i][j])>(sum=sum+type[i+1][j]))`.  Why the assignments where you should only be testing values?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin how to show the indexing of i ? I actually have to show that as well along with the biggest

Comment: Added tracking the row where the biggest sum occurs to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your program has the following errors:**

1. `if((sum=sum+type[i][j])>(sum=sum+type[i+1][j]))` will go out-of-bound of array.
2. The highest value must be printed outside of all the loops and assigned during loop execution.

---

**There you go with correct program:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int arr[][3] = {{3, 31, 19}, {34, 2, 1}, {0, 0, 9}, {3, 0, 6}, {11, 9, 5}};
    size_t len = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
    int sum = 0, largest = 0, index = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            sum += arr[i][j];

            if (sum > largest) {
                largest = sum; // getting the largest number
                index = i;     // getting the index of the largest number
            }
        }
        printf("The sum of %d is: %d\n", i + 1, sum);
        sum = 0;
    }

    printf("Highest: %d with %d\n", largest, index);

    return 0;
}
```

This will print the highest number alongside the index where the highest number is provided.

You'll then get something like:

```
The sum of 1 is: 53
The sum of 2 is: 37
The sum of 3 is: 9
The sum of 4 is: 9
The sum of 5 is: 25
Highest: 53 with 0 // 0 is the index of the array, not counting as a number
```

Comment: how do i print the index of i along with the largest?

Comment: @brogrammer simply declare a variable, suppose `index` and assign the value of `i` alongside the assignment of `sum` in the if condition. (I've updated the code)

Comment: Be careful. If all elements / sums are negative, you will not find the largest or the correct index. (but otherwise nicely done)

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of problems. `i` and `j` are not declared, and you read beyond the end of `type` with `type[i+1][j]`. You must fix both.

To find the largest sum, you need a separate variable that holds the largest of the sums seen and then after you exit your last loop, then output the biggest sum, e.g.

(**updated to include row where largest sum occurs**)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main (void) {
    
    int type[5][3] = {{3,31,19}, {34,2,1}, {0,0,9}, {3,0,6}, {11,9,5}},
        biggest = INT_MIN,                  /* variable to hold biggest sum */
        bigindex = 0;                       /* variable to hold row of biggest */
        
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {           /* loop over each row */
        int sum = 0;                        /* declare/initialize sum = 0 */
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {       /* loop over each int */
            sum += type[i][j];              /* add int to sum */
        }
        if (sum > biggest) {                /* compare sum to biggest sum */
            biggest = sum;                  /* update biggest if sum larger */
            bigindex = i + 1;               /* update row where it occurs */
        }
        printf ("Total sum type[%d] = %d\n",i+1, sum);  /* output sum */
    }
    /* output largest sum and row where it occurred */
    printf ("Largest sum: %d at row %d\n", biggest, bigindex);
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/biggestsum
Total sum type[1] = 53
Total sum type[2] = 37
Total sum type[3] = 9
Total sum type[4] = 9
Total sum type[5] = 25
Largest sum: 53 at row 1
```

Let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 0):

Store sum of all the 5 rows of `int type[5][3]` in any array, say `sum[5]` and then find the highest of them and then print their `index+1` no. to show that, this row has the highest sum.

**Example:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define ROW 2
#define COLUMN 3
int main(void)
{
  int type[ROW][COLUMN] = { {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}};
  int sum[ROW] = {0, 0};
  int i, j, row = 0, highest = 0;

  for ( i = 0; i < ROW; ++i)
    for ( j = 0; j < COLUMN; ++j)
      sum[i] += type[i][j];

  for ( i = 0; i < ROW; ++i)
    if(highest < sum[i])
    {
        highest = sum[i];
        row = i;
    }
  printf("Row %d has the highest sum value %d.\n", row, highest);
  return 0;
}
```